# Need help getting a cascading form to do multiple selections?

Tags: jquery

I have a basic form that filters by animal type, ('Mammals' shows 'Dog' & 'Squirrel' etc). However, I need it to ALSO use multiple selection where selecting both 'Mammals' and 'Bird' would show the combined results ('Dog','Squirrel', 'Hawk') instead of one just replacing the other.

Here is the code of what I'm working with. Any help is appreciated! Thanks.

```js
$('select#list').change(function() {
    var target = $(this).data('target');
    $(target).children().addClass('hide');
    var show = $("option:selected", this).data('show');
    $(show).removeClass('hide');
});
```

```css
.hide {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="list" multiple="multiple" data-target=".my-info-1">
  <option value="32" data-show=".Mam">Mammals</option>
  <option value="3" data-show=".Bird">Birds</option>
  <option value="4">Reptiles</option>
</select>
<select id="butts" class="my-info-1" multiple="multiple">
  <option class="Mam hide">Squirrel</option>
  <option class="Mam hide">Dog</option>
  <option class="Bird hide">Hawk</option>
  <option class="hss hide">Snake</option>
</select>
```

Comment: looks like you're assuming hat `option:selected` is a single thing instead of an array... my guess: look into jquery each ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn the `data-show` of all selected options into a comma-delimited list:

```js
$('select#list').change(function() {
    var target = $(this).data('target'),
        show = $("option:selected", this).map(function () {
            return $(this).data('show');
        }).get().join(",");

    $("#debug").text(show);

    $(target).children().addClass('hide').filter(show).removeClass('hide');
});
```

```css
select {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
.hide {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="list" multiple="multiple" data-target=".my-info-1">
  <option value="32" data-show=".Mam">Mammals</option>
  <option value="3" data-show=".Bird">Birds</option>
  <option value="4" data-show=".hss">Reptiles</option>
</select>
<select id="butts" class="my-info-1" multiple="multiple">
  <option class="Mam hide">Squirrel</option>
  <option class="Mam hide">Dog</option>
  <option class="Bird hide">Hawk</option>
  <option class="hss hide">Snake</option>
</select>

<p id="debug"></p>
```